# Why do Photoshop files start with 8BPS?

Tags: photoshop, hexdump, abbreviation

From pretty much the beginning of time Photoshop files have begun with 8BPS. (I have verified this back to version 2.5) It must have had some meaning at some point.

The 8B I thought might refer to bits/channel, but it makes no difference saving it 16 or 32. PS is probably PhotoShop, but might not be. Something to do with the way Mac saved files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`8B` is shorthand for Adobe. I guess "eight bee" sounds a *little* bit like Adobe; more so if you're Italian - "Otto Bee".

And `PS` is "Photoshop". So, `8BPS` is "Adobe Photoshop".

8B crops up in quite a few places in Adobe file extensions or internal types. [Wikipedia has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8B).

Answer (score 0):

That is just the Signature to identify the file as a Photoshop file. From the Specification:

```
Signature: always equal to '8BPS' . Do not try to read the file if the signature does not match this value.
```

See the [Photoshop File Format Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_pgfId-1036097) for more detailied information.

Comment: Yes I know. The question is, why?

Comment: To know how to parse the file. If you open the file in PS, PS has to know how to handle the data read from the file. With the first 4 bytes set to 8BPS, it can determine that the file is a photoshop file and parse it accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I obviously need to change the question. I'm curious to know why "8BPS" was chosen, rather than any other value.

Comment: There likely is no "Why".  Java .JAR files start with 0xCAFEBABE (why? because its "cute").  Old DOS executables start with MZ (why? Because those are the initials of the guy who made the format).  These files start with 8BPS. (why?  no good reason... because it has to start with something

Comment: Well you gave two good reasons then bailed on the last! I really doubt it's just plucked out of thin air. I reckon Thomas Knoll would know, I will see if I can get an answer.